# How Ultisnips transforms text instantly in Vim?

Tags: vim, transform, ultisnips

[SirVer/ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) is a very productive plugin for writing scripts in Vim. But anyone knows **How Ultisnips transforms text instantly in Vim** as shown in the gif. Ultisnips in this example is transforming every character in text "This is the subtitle" into minus sign immediately after character is being typed.

[image: ultisnip transformation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What it looks like**

From what I understand it looks like they are cheating ;)
Here's a hint that will give you the basice idea. 
So step one, enter some text.
[image]
Then just `yyp` and `s/./_/g` and you are done

[image]

Or `s/./-/g`:
[image]

**How it's done (Well, most likely)**

So they are basically intercepting each symbol insertion.
But how? It looks like they are using autocommand for specifc event, namely, for [CursorMovedI](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorMovedI), which is triggered "after the cursor was moved in Insert mode".

You can easily find autocommand binding if you take a look to [the source code](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet_manager.py).

**Alternative approach**

VIM is a console text editor and text formatting of this kind is not something widely supported in terminals. There are some workarounds though, like using special utf-8 characters (of course, text should be encoded accordingly). [Here's](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Create_underlines,_overlines,_and_strikethroughs_using_combining_characters) a code snippet that you can use for this approach:

```
" modify selected text using combining diacritics
command! -range -nargs=0 Overline        call s:CombineSelection(<line1>, <line2>, '0305')
command! -range -nargs=0 Underline       call s:CombineSelection(<line1>, <line2>, '0332')
command! -range -nargs=0 DoubleUnderline call s:CombineSelection(<line1>, <line2>, '0333')
command! -range -nargs=0 Strikethrough   call s:CombineSelection(<line1>, <line2>, '0336')

function! s:CombineSelection(line1, line2, cp)
  execute 'let char = "\u'.a:cp.'"'
  execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/\%V[^[:cntrl:]]/&'.char.'/ge'
endfunction
```

But as you can see it's not ideal:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand this. So how it can be implemented such that the vim substitution is able to be executed every time I type a character? Should there be some thread to watch the line if the text is changing or not?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very inspiring. But my quesiton is asked mainly due to calling for an explanation why the instant change could be made by Vim when character is being typed. How could vim do that substitution instantly?

Comment: @Life just a sec, I'll add explanation )

Comment: Thank you! I shall wait and feel it a little beyond my current understanding of vim. @shabunc

Comment: Yes, it really helps me! I should learn some **autocmd**. Thank you! @shabunc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ultisnips](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/rst.snippets#L153-L155) something like this:

```
snippet ssec "Subsection" b
${1:${VISUAL:Subsection name}}
`!p snip.rv = rst_char_len(t[1])*'-'`
```

The code above works on `rst.snippets` which have subsections "ssec"
but you have to see the whole code because function "rst_char_len" is defined in the same file to provide the length of the string you are typing. The global definition which allows us to perform this stunt 
can be read [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/e24d33f96a95332dde0edaa7e7e3e7a64244de56/UltiSnips/rst.snippets#L8-L128).